# Android 4.3: no external memory available? Mount extSdCard?

Tags: android, memory, external, sd-card, android-sdcard

I have this problem,, which occured while using CM10.1 for a while. It just happend after a month or so.

My exterdan Micro Sd-card 16GB was unable to reached out to which I mentioned when trying to access Gallery. I can't even save media send by Whatsapp or take pictures.

In Settings > Storage Settings i mentioned that Android is showing me the SD-card and is able to calculate total storage of this SD-card. So tthis is telling me that the SD-card is working in Android but not able to use it somehow.

- I have checked if it is working on my PC (yes it is)
- I have already formatted the SD-card in FAT32
- In root explorer I can find the SD-card as extSdCard, /mnt/extSdCard
- I have reinstalled another Firmware, but same problem occured

So something is wrong in Android refering to the SD-card for external memory I guess..

Comment: Eh, moderator, perhaps this question needs to be moved to StackExchange forum.

Comment: This sounds like a question for a CM support forum, as there's enough potentially unique innovation there that could also be the source of non-standard problems.